# Is there a Yammer REST API to get the users geo location

Tags: yammer

In users.json, there is no details about it.
Is there a REST api which can provide geo location like latitude/longitude, IP Address from where the user has logged in?

In Yammer web page, I can see there is an option for Network Admin to see the user activity, where it displays the user's IP address, application, etc.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This type of information isn't available via the product or its APIs today.